# smooth parametrized journey 3d representation of 4d dataset

Tags: data-analysis, visualization, projection, stereographic-projections, 4-manifolds

I have a dataset of $N$ points in 4-D space.

$ \left \{  \left( x_1^{(1)}, x_2^{(1)}, x_3^{(1)}, x_4^{(1)}  \right), \left( x_1^{(2)}, x_2^{(2)}, x_3^{(2)}, x_4^{(2)}  \right), ... \left( x_1^{(N)}, x_2^{(N)}, x_3^{(N)}, x_4^{(N)}  \right) \right \}$

Want to generate 3-D scatter plots of the dataset, somehow smoothly transitioning 3-D $xyz$ projection axes from 123 to 124 to 134 to 234 and then back to 123

Is there a way to smoothly incrementally map and re-map 3-D projections like this to journey through all of 4-space?

Apologies is this question is not worded precisely enough.  I am open to suggestions on how to clarify.

Is a method scalable to generic 3-D representation of data in higher dimensions?